# Regular Expressions in OleDB

Tags: sql, regex, vb.net, oledb

How can I use regular expressions in an OleDB connection? I tried this:

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
conn.ConnectionString = "my little secret"
conn.Open()

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand( _
    "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title REGEXP '^.*[a-z][a-z][0-9].*$'", cmd)
Dim dt As DataTable = cmd.ExecuteQuery()
```

but it results in a syntax error (missing operator).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get all the books with title contain word `hello` then you can use sql `LIKE` operator you don't need regex, just change your sql command to this,

```
"SELECT * FROM books WHERE title Like '%hello%' "
```

Update:

If you're not using some complex regex then i still suggest to go with LIKE operator, see some examples [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx). And if you have to have regex then you can create a function in Vb.Net and import the dll into sql server as `CLR function` and use that, see [details](http://www.sqllion.com/2010/12/pattern-matching-regex-in-t-sql/)

Comment: I know this. Tried to make the example as simple as possible, but now I updated the question to have a more regex-like expression.